# Create a taxonomy field as a site column in REST

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, metadata, taxonomy, get-site-columns

I need to create a taxonomy column as a site column in a site collection programmatically with REST. I only have access to REST (via flow) , I have no development capabilities besides rest.

I can create a normal column (Text, number etc) very easily with /_api/Web/Fields/createfieldasxml but with a metadata column we need a type called 'Notes' which I get an error of not well formed JSON when I attempt this.

Has anyone achieved this using REST calls ?

Comment: anybody any know-how ???

Comment: Maybe post a copy of the headers and sample body you are using so someone can take a stab at it in their own environment?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    var web = ctx.get_web();  
    var fields = web.get_fields();  
    field = fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("SessionTopics");  
    txField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);  
    txField.set_sspId(termStoreId);  
    txField.set_termSetId(termSetId);  
    //txField.update();  
    txField.updateAndPushChanges(true);  
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){                         
    },function(sender,args){      
          console.log(args.get_message());    
    });  
}
```

Grab your site column
Cast it to a taxonomyfield
update the termstoreID, termsetID (get these from taxonomy page in sharepoint)
and then do the usual executequery.
DONE!